# How to generate correlated random numbers?

Tags: python

I want to generate two random integers in python, which are correlated. 
Let's say that integer `n` is a random integer between 0 and 10, and I want integer `q` to be in the same range but be not more that `n`. Any suggestions?

```
from __future__ import division

from random import randint

population = randint(100, 1000)
number_of_successes = randint(1, 100)
number_of_fails = population-number_of_successes
probability = number_of_successes/population
```

Comment: `q, n = sorted(random.sample(range(11), 2))`?

Comment: and what is relation between your question and your code?

Comment: The rest of my code is about to be a randomly generated numbers for probability calculations, and I need numbers that cannot be bigger then these.

Answer (score 1):

> n integer is a random integer between 0 and 10, and i want integer q to be in the same range but be not more that n

So `q` is not in "the same range" as `n`. It is in the range `[0, n]` (or `[0, n)`, this is not clear from the question).

This is quite a simple task:

```
n = randint(100, 1000)
q = randint(100, n)
```

If `q` must not be equal to `n`, remove `n` from the range of `q`:

```
n = randint(100, 1000)
q = randint(100, n - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import random

first_number = random.randint(0, 10)

second_number = random.randint(0, first_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first variable as the second parameter

```
from __future__ import division

from random import randint

population = randint(0 ,1000)
number_of_successes = randint(0 , population)
number_of_fails = population-number_of_successes
probability = number_of_successes/population
```